# What's this tree in the opening of Neon Genesis Evangelion?

Tags: reference, evangelion

In the first few seconds of [the opening to *Neon Genesis Evangelion*](https://youtu.be/t-QSmNReDyI?t=6), there is a tree-like thing with a bunch of writing in a language I don't recognize, along with what appears to be a bit of Hebrew:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Given that there's a bunch of Christian symbolism in the show, I'm thinking this might be a Jewish/Christian thing. **What is this tree?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is the [Kabbalah Tree of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_of_life_(Kabbalah)), a symbol used over time through a variety of cultures, and represents an attempt to understand and unify the connections between various concepts of life and the universe.

[image]

As given by the name, is also related to the [Kabbalah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabbalah) (which is seen in the show during Human Instrumentality). You correctly identified some of the writing to be in Hebrew, but most of the writing is in Latin.

Comment: IIRC aren't the opponents in NGE "Angels", and aren't Angels one of the things mapped out in the Kabbalah?

Comment: @gowenfawr According to Wikipedia: "The nodes are also associated to deities, angels, celestial bodies, values, single colors or combinations of them, and specific numbers". In context of NGE lore however, there doesn't appear to be a stated connection between the angels in the show and the Kabbalah Tree of Life ([as far as I can see](https://wiki.evageeks.org/Tree_of_Life)).